# How can I find functions satisfying the Bessel equation $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t)+p(t)\frac d{dt}y(t)+q(t)y(t)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We are tasked with finding the functions $u(t), Q(t)$ such that the conversion $y(t) = u(t)v(t)$ takes us from
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t) + p(t)\dfrac{d}{dt}y(t) + q(t)y(t) = 0
\end{align}
to the form
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}u(t) + Q(t)u(t)=0.
\end{align}

From then on we must use this to solve $t^2\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t) + t\dfrac{d}{dt}y(t) + \left(t^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)y(t) = 0$.

My take was this: I started differentiating (misusing the notation to make it easier to read)
\begin{align}
&y(t)=u(t)v(t)\\
&y'(t)=u'(t)v(t)+u(t)v'(t)\\
&y''(t)=u''(t)v(t) + 2u'(t)v'(t) + u(t)v''(t)
\end{align}
thus the original equation gives
\begin{align}
u''(t) v(t) + 2u'(t)v'(t) + u(t)v''(t)+ p(t) \left[ u'(t)v(t)+u(t)v'(t) \right] + q(t)u(t)v(t) = 0
\end{align}
dividing by $v(t)$ (we can assume it's nonzero) we have
\begin{align}
\boxed{u''(t)} + \dfrac{2u'(t)v'(t)}{v(t)} + \boxed{u(t)} \dfrac{v''(t)}{v(t)} + p(t)u'(t) + \boxed{u(t)}\dfrac{p(t)v'(t)}{v(t)} + \boxed{u(t)}q(t)=0.
\end{align}
All the boxed terms give us (by common factor) the $Q(t)$ we ask for. However the remaining non-boxed terms must be zero right? So let's ask the equation to zero this for us:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{2u'(t)v'(t)}{v(t)} + p(t)u'(t) = 0\\
\implies u'(t) \left[ 2\dfrac{v'(t)}{v(t)} + p(t) \right] = 0\\
\implies u(t) = c \ \lor \ 2\left( \ln v(t) \right)' + p(t) = 0\\
\implies u(t) = c \ \lor \ v(t) = e^{-\int \left(\dfrac{p(t)}{2}dt\right)}.
\end{align}

This is where I have arrived, and I am not sure how to proceed. Can we assume that $u(t)$ cannot be constant? What about $v(t)$? Nowhere is this asked to find right?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But then the coefficient of $u(t)$ becomes very complicated...

Comment: You mean $v(t)$? They look kind of the same in latex.

Comment: I mean for example the equation $y''+ty'-y=0$.  With $y=uv$, it becomes $u''-(\frac{1}{4}t^2+\frac{3}{4})u=0$.  The first eqution has a simple solution $y=t$.  Make a guess for the second equation.

Comment: @BobDobbs you solved one question for one function. I am searching for every function that satisfies a property.

Comment: Everything you've done so far is scratch work. At the end of the day, all that matters is that your chosen $u$ and $v$ result in the desired form. You don't have to be rigorous in coming up with them, only in checking that upon substitution they yield the correct form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment
...
From then on we must solve
$$t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+t\frac{dy}{dt}+(t^2-\frac{1}{4})y=0.\tag{*}$$
Then by dividing $(*)$ by $t^2$, we get
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{t}\frac{dy}{dt}+(1-\frac{1}{4t^2})y=0.$$
Now, here, $p=p(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ and $q=q(t)=1-\frac{1}{4t^2}$.

Then, we apply Algevristis's transformation. Let $y=u(t)v(t)$ where
$$v=v(t)=e^{-\int \frac{p(t)}{2}dt}=e^{-\int \frac{1}{2t}dt}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln t}=t^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
According to Algevristis's transformation, $u=u(t)$ satisfies the equation
$$u''+(\frac{v''}{v}+\frac{v'}{v}p+q)u=0.$$

We find $v''=\frac{3}{4}t^{-\frac{5}{2}}$ and $v'=-\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}$. If we put $v, v', v'', p, q$ in the equation above, we get
$$u''+(\frac{3}{4}t^{-2}-\frac{1}{2}t^{-2}+1-\frac{1}{4}t^{-2})u=0.$$
Wow. A miracle happens! After cancellations we get clean
$$u''+u=0.\tag{**}$$
Now, we can quickly reach a solution. The solution of $(**)$ is  $u=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t$, so the solution of $(*)$ is
$$y=c_1\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{t}}+c_1\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}$$
because $y$ was $uv$.

My thoughts about the transformation: Is the equation $(*)$ fake Bessel equation?